# Queries on User VS User per Gender and Age

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, add-on

I am using the Google Analytics API add-on and mentioned a mistake in my queries' results.

Indeed, when I query "users", the number in return is around 200 000

However, when I query "users" per "gender", it returns a total of around 100 000 users.

Does it mean that Google Analytics didn't identified 50% of them?

What I did:

ga:users in one query

VS

ga:users
ga:userAgeBracket,ga:userGender in the second query

I expect to get the same number of users but it doesn't work.

Anyone can help or help me understand why?

Comment: Hi welcome to SO.  To better answers your questions please provide some code to what you've done and also outline your specific problem clearly.  Broad questions with no code are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the relevant [support article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2799357?hl=en), it is very unlikely, that you'll get the demographic details for all of your users:

> Demographics and interests data may only be available for a subset of
>   your users, and may not represent the overall composition of your
>   traffic: Analytics cannot collect the demographics and interests
>   information if the DoubleClick cookie or the Device Advertising ID is
>   not present, or if no activity profile is included.

This means, that seeing a lower number of users, when demographic dimensions are applied, is not an error, but an expected result. As suggested in the article, you can check the share of users with demographic data on the Analytics web UI. (Although it might be the same ratio, that you get by using and ommiting the demographic dimensions.)